# Erro com retrofit

Tags: android, rest, http, retrofit

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

public interface RestApi {

@GET("/posts")
Call<Model[]> getWheatherReport();
```

}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
String url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
TextView txt_city, txt_status, txt_humidity, txt_pressure;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txt_city = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_city);
    txt_status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_status);
    txt_humidity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_humidity);
    txt_pressure = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_press);


    getReport();
}

void getReport() {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RestApi service = retrofit.create(RestApi.class);

    Call<Model[]> call = service.getWheatherReport();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Model[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<Model[]> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            Log.v("CONSOLES", "--> "+response.body());
            try {

                Integer userId = response.body()[0].getUserId();

                Integer id = response.body()[0].getId();

                String title = response.body()[0].getTitle().toString();

                String body = response.body()[0].getBody().toString();

                txt_city.setText("city  :  " + userId);
                txt_status.setText("status  :  " + id);
                txt_humidity.setText("humidity  : " + title);
                txt_pressure.setText("pressure  :  " + body);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.v("CONSOLES-ERRO", "--> "+t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

}

Já tentei vários tutoriais e continua o erro.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fala Roberto,

O seu problema está no Model, para recebe-lo em modo array, você está fazendo errado no Retrofit:

Teria de ser:

```
Callback<List<Model>>
```

no lugar de:

```
Callback<Model[]>
```

Abraços.

Comment: Fala Leonardo.
Eu ja tentei dessa forma e continua dando problema, antes de como ta agora tava dessa forma que você disse

Comment: Você mudou também onde tem Call<Model[]>?? Posta o seu arquivo Model pra eu dar uma olhada, pode editar o seu post. Abraços.

Comment: Leonardo, já resolvi. O erro estava em /posts/posts/ na url.